# Find the gcd of ($x^2 + 1, x^3 + x +1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

> Find the gcd of ($x^2 + 1, x^3 + x +1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$

I have no idea how to do this really. Any help is appreciated. Here is my attempt:

$x^3 + x + 1$ = $x(x^2 + 1) + 1$

$x^2 + 1 = (x^2)(1) + 1$

In particular I am confused about how I am supposed to find the gcd in the field $\mathbb{Z}_3$? Thanks.

Comment: Your second step is not right. You want to divide the first remainder ($1$) into the first divisor ($x^2+1$) and get a quotient of $x^2+1$ and a remainder of zero. The remainder at the preceding step is your gcd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x^3+x+1=x(x^2+1)+1$, using the Euclidean Algorithm, we find:

$$\text{gcd}(x^3+x+1, x^2+1)=\text{gcd}(x^2+1, x^3+x+1-x(x^2+1))=\text{gcd}(x^2+1, 1)=1$$

Comment: That's it? Is this all I have to do each time?

Comment: Yes, as long as $K$ is a field, then just use the Euclidean algorithm in order to find the GCD of two polynomials in $K[X]$.